# scrolling is not working in a page opened within a page in appium

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

scrolling is working fine in normal pages in android application.But if i click on any element it will open as a new page over existing page,there scrolling is not working in appium automation using touchaction.here is my code to scrolldown

```
public void scrollDown(AppiumDriver driver){
  try {
    int height = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
    touchAction.longPress(5, height * 2 / 3).moveTo(5, height / 
    3).release().perform();
      }
  catch(Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}}
```

Comment: Can you add code you use and error you got?

Comment: And am not getting any error.if i loop trough this code its working fine in normal pages.But any pages like popup(i mean opening over current page)its not working

Comment: Please add the code in your question and not in the comments, you can use the insert code button while editing to easily insert it and get it tidy. (Button is on the top toolbar in the edit window)

Comment: Try changing the 5 to 200 or any other number in you code **touchAction.longPress(5, height * 2 / 3).moveTo(5, height / 
    3)**  to **touchAction.longPress(200, height * 2 / 3).moveTo(200, height / 
    3)**

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not starting your swipe within the boundaries of the swipe view. A good way to debug if this is the case is to activate the `Pointer location` option within androids developer options then watch where the automation is touching.

Now if this is the issue like I expect it is then you need to do a little bit of math around where a valid point is. I would recommend looking at the following functions

```
MobileElement el = myElement; // Pretend this is a real element :D
el.getSize();   // This has a getHeight() and getWidth() function
el.getLocation; // This has a getX() and getY() function
```

Now what you can do (assuming you are swiping in a rectangular field is find out what the smallest and largest x and y positions are.

To get the Y positions is easy simply:

```
int smallestY = el.getLocation.getY();
int largestY = smallestYPosition + el.getSize().getHeight();
```

Now to get the X positions:

```
int smallestX = el.getLocation.getX();
int largestX = smallestX + el.getSize().getHeight();
```

Now use these points when swiping.

This will work in basic cases but to my understanding if the element is wider than the screen size issues will appear so you will have to handle that.

Hopefully this helps you develop a way that works for your given case. Unfortunately with the currently given information I cannot provide an answer that will work out of the box for you.